# Where may setting about last opened window style be stored?

Tags: powershell, window, styles

I make an app with [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier), and I want it to open minimized on start. Unfortunately, [not all app honor the requested style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53423001/3416774), so either using PowerShell command

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized 'D:\GitHub\Web-wrapper\Google Keep-win32-ia32\Google Keep.exe'
```

or setting its property as minimized

[image]

won't work.

One workaround solution is via regedit (see the second link), but as a standalone app, there is no way to know. So I guess the only way to find the setting that force it to start minimized is via its [source code](https://github.com/ooker777/Web-wrapper), but it doesn't seem to have any config file.

Do you know how to set it starts minimized with PowerShell? And in general, where may such setting be stored?

Comment: Windows has API for that, use `WinExec()`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make it an answer? It seems that I need to [use C# to call it](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5laa3x/easily_calling_windows_apis_from_powershell/dbun2bd), and it's basically out of my ability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 7.6.9, Nativefier has implemented this feature
([issue #522](https://github.com/tribut/nativefier/commit/b1c469dbbbf4dc87eec95959623b7bec90d603d6)).

According to the
[documentation](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier/blob/master/docs/api.md#tray),
the syntax is as follows:

```
nativefier --tray start-in-tray
```